# Docker/Podman Selinux Udica - Rootless Container unable to mount/run from mapped entrypoint script

Tags: selinux, container, podman

I like to use steamcmd as dockercontainer rootless for my serveruser. But steamcmd should normally installed with normal user under /opt/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh

I created a custom steamcmd.sh which run a docker/podman container with the steamcmd arks and pass the caller user id to a env.

I replace the default entrypoint-script with a custom one which is /opt/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.docker.sh (steamuser)

When I run the container as root - all is working, but when I try it with the server user I get a "Error: error stat'ing file `/opt/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.docker.sh`: Permission denied: OCI permission denied"

My selinux is on permissive on host. So I check the logs and it give me following message:

```
Mai 06 02:13:48 host setroubleshoot[81420]: SELinux is preventing steamcmd.replace from read access on the file steamcmd.docker.sh.
                                                      If you believe that steamcmd.replac should be allowed read access on the steamcmd.docker.sh file by default.
                                                      # ausearch -c 'steamcmd.replace' --raw | audit2allow -M my-steamcmdreplace
                                                      # semodule -X 300 -i my-steamcmdreplace.pp
```

I generated the file and it show me following:

```
module my-steamcmdreplace 1.0;

require {
    type container_t;
    type etc_t;
    class file entrypoint;
}

#============= container_t ==============
allow container_t etc_t:file entrypoint;
```

A second selinux message is

```
Mai 05 01:30:29 host setroubleshoot[3763945]: SELinux is preventing /bin/dash from entrypoint access on the file /usr/bin/steamcmd.replace.
                                                        If you believe that dash should be allowed entrypoint access on the steamcmd.replace file by default.
```

I added the modules but nothing changes - so I tried with udica to generate container policies - but it works only for a container which is running - so I used a container running from root.

I added the rule manually to the udica generated module which contains following:

```
(block steamcmd
    (blockinherit container)
    (allow process process ( capability ( chown dac_override fowner fsetid kill net_bind_service setfcap setgid setpcap setuid sys_chroot ))) 

    (allow process usr_t ( dir ( getattr ioctl lock open read search ))) 
    (allow process usr_t ( file ( getattr ioctl lock open read ))) 
    (allow process usr_t ( sock_file ( getattr open read ))) 
    (allow process usr_t ( dir ( add_name create getattr ioctl lock open read remove_name rmdir search setattr write ))) 
    (allow process usr_t ( file ( append create getattr ioctl lock map open read rename setattr unlink write ))) 
    (allow process usr_t ( sock_file ( append getattr open read write ))) 
    (allow container_t etc_t (file (entrypoint)))
)
```

The command to run that container from serveruser is:

```
podman run --network=host --dns 8.8.8.8 --security-opt label=type:steamcmd.process -t --rm --entrypoint 'steamcmd.replace' --name steamcmd -v /opt/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.docker.sh:/usr/bin/steamcmd.replace:z -v .:/data docker.io/steamcmd/steamcmd:latest +force_install_dir /data validate
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Can nobody help me with that stuff?

Comment: If you ask the question here: https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions   you might get an answer. Some of the Podman core developers are following that forum.